# iPhone wouldn't launch apps, restarted and now showing Apple sign-on screen

Tags: iphone, restart

I restarted my iPhone 4S because the apps kept backing out instead of loading but my phone has been showing the Apple sign on the screen for about an hour. I've already tried pressing the home button and shut off button. What else can I do?

Answer (score 1):

Holding down both the Home Button and the button on the top of the phone for 10 seconds will force the phone to do a hard reboot.